# Does Google prefer 1-year SSL certificate over 3, 5-year SSL certificates?

Tags: google, security-certificate

I'm currently working on converting my company's site to SSL and the developer I'm working with asked if Google preferred 1-year certificates over 3-year certificates.

I thought I vaguely remembered that issue being asked in a Google conference (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBhZ6S0PFCY) but upon watching it again I guess not.

So this is just a quick question: has anyone came across any material where Google said a preference for the length of the certificate or if they don't care either way?

Comment: I don't think they care either way. But if it is like domains they may prefer longer registered ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a chance to look at some schema and data elements that Google keeps a couple of years ago so I am going off of 2 year old memory. There was nothing that I recall about the lifetime of the certificate. However, there were metrics for certificates including dates and who issued the certificate. As I recall, the business rule was: Is the certificate current, valid, and from a quality issuer? Keep that in mind. Not all certificate issuers are the same and a trust score is applied to each. So if you are working on certificates, some issuers are more trusted because of the care they take in issuing certificates. For example, choose GoDaddy over BobsCertShop located in the back of BobsSurfShop and Grille.

Comment: What if Bobs surf shop is a GoDaddy reseller? Just keep that in mind too - sometimes places like your host/Bob "mask" an SSL that is actually something trusted like Globalsign or Geotrust deep down. Ask who their origin issuer is before you buy anywhere.

Comment: If Bob was a GoDaddy re-seller, then that would be fine of course. You make a good point about re-sellers. My example was a bit extreme to make a point and have some fun. But you are absolutely right. The actual issuer should (if I remember right) be on the certificate. It has been over a decade since I was a certificate issuer and I have not kept up- admittedly. I shutdown my certificate offerings when I shutdown my web host. Both had become more of a pain than the money was worth. People should not always look for the cheapest option when a quality option often does not cost too much.

Comment: @dhaupin By the way, BobsSurfShop and Grille has the best fish and steak tacos- surf and turf! Much better than CarolsOrganic where you get seaweed and grass- you know what food eats. I forgot to [at]you before.